# Moving files with an extension into a location

Tags: bash

How could I move all .txt files from a folder and all included folders into a target directory .

And preferably rename them to the folder they where included in, although thats not that important. I'm not exactly familiar with bash.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To recursively move files, combine `find` with `mv`.

```
find src/dir/ -name '*.txt' -exec mv -t target/dir/ -- {} +
```

Or if on a UNIX system without GNU's version of `find`, such as macOS, use:

```
find src/dir/ -name '*.txt' -exec mv -- {} target/dir/ ';'
```

To rename the files when you move them it's trickier. One way is to have a loop that uses `"${var//from/to}"` to replace all occurrences of `from` with `to` in `$var`.

```
find src/dir/ -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd $'\0' file; do
    mv -- "$file" target/dir/"${file//\//_}"
done
```

This is ugly because `from` is a slash, which needs to be escaped as `\/`.

See also:

- [Unix.SE: Understanding `IFS= read -r line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)
- [BashFAQ: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: A version that'll work with files containing embedded newlines, or start with spaces: `find src/dir -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//\//_}"' _ {} ';'`

Comment: Using `while read file` won't handle filenames with backslashes unless it's made `read -r file`. I would also suggest using `-print0` and `while IFS= read -r -d '' file` to correctly handle filenames with newlines.

Comment: ..I'd also suggest `-exec mv -t target/dir/ -- {} +` for users with GNU tools, to be able to pass as many filenames as possible to each copy of `mv`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Updates made. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
find source -name '*.txt' | xargs -I files mv files target
```

This will work faster than any option with -exec, since it will not invoke a singe mv process for every file which needs to be moved.

Comment: Much, much faster than the accepted answer.  Note that for robustness it's a good idea to use zero-terminated filename strings: `find source -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I files mv files target`

Comment: I tried this but it is moving unexpected filetypes. I wanted to move just .srt files but for some reason, this is moving .srt and .mkv files too. I tried using Cooperised's method and am seeing the same behavior. In testing I am in a directory with ten sub-directories, each subdirectory has several .srts, and several .mkv files. Why is this command moving the unexpected .mkv files? For what it's worth I am on Mac OS and using stock Terminal App with stock Bash.

Test command is below:

`find . '*.srt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I files mv files`.

Comment: @cooperised, ..."faster"? `xargs -I` starts a new copy of `mv` for every single file found! It's nothing remotely like fast. (`xargs` _can_ pass multiple arguments to each subprocess, but `-I` turns that off).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right of course about the multiple `mv`s.  But I didn't claim it was fast in any objective sense, just that it was faster than the accepted answer - and all three variants of the accepted answer *also* spawned a new copy of `mv` for every single file at the time I made my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one level:

```
mv *.txt */*.txt target/directory/somewhere/.
```