# recovering the files that were deleted in Linux by using mv

Tags: linux, sh

I have followed the suggestions on the web page :

[Moving files with an extension into a location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345714/moving-files-with-an-extension-into-a-location)

specifically, on a HPC cluster, I have used :

```
find . -name '*.R' | xargs -I files mv files target

find . -name '*.sh' | xargs -I files mv files target
```

and I have lost all the files having the extension ".R" or ".sh".

How can I recover the files that have these extensions ?  Thanks !

Comment: Firstly, shut down the pc that has the hard drive connected immediately. Then boot from system usb or cd and run filesystem specific tool to restore deleted files.

Comment: Thank you. Oh well, those files were on SLURM HPC.

Answer (score 0):

You have executed the command incorrectly. What it did was to rename all those files to the target name.
Each time xargs is run it has mashed the previous file. So you will only have the last one with the name target.

You can test to see what that command does by running it on test files by adding to the end of the command `-vf`:  `find . -name '*.R' | xargs -I files mv files target -vf`

I don't think you will be able to recover the files. I am very sorry.

As you have been told, you will have to try to recover those files with a specific tool for that purpose.